# "The summer before last", "in the summer last year", or "last summer"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say today is September the first, 2020 and I want say that I did something in the summer of 2019. I cannot say *I went on vacation last summer* because even though the summer of 2020 has just ended, it would still reffered to the summer of 2020,right? What would be the most natural way to refer to the summer of 2019, when I am in September the first 2020? Do the following sound natural?

> I went on vacation **in the summer before last**.
>
> I went on vacation **in the summer last year**.

Comment: The most natural would be "last summer", but all of these are grammatically acceptable.

Comment: I would simply refer to this as `I went on vacation last summer`

Comment: _This summer_ is the summer of the current year, so the previous year's is _last summer_. To make it absolutely clear you could say _in the summer of last year_.

Comment: As I write, *the summer **before last*** refers to summer **2018**, whereas all the other variants refer to summer **2019** (except ***this** summer*, which will be later in **2020**).

Comment: I am sorry, but I am really confused. So if it is September the first 2020 and I say "I went on vacation last summer", it means I went on vacation in the summer of 2019, not the summer of 2020 that just ended. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context, *Last summer* refers to summer from a previous year. For instance, an article [Donald Trump touted Apple manufacturing jobs in Austin on Wednesday. Here’s what you need to know.](https://www.texastribune.org/2019/11/20/donald-trump-austin-visit-apple/) created on November 20, 2019 refers to an event from 2018 and uses *last summer* to describe that summer:

> **Last summer**, the company signed the Trump administration’s Pledge to
>   America’s Workers and committed to creating 10,000 training
>   opportunities for American workers and students over the next five
>   years.

*This summer* refers to summer from a current year. For example, an article [Trump Ukraine pressure campaign was ‘a domestic political errand,’](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/11/21/impeachment-trump-ukraine-pressure-was-domestic-political-errand-fiona-hill-says.html) from November, 2019 refers to the 2019 summer as *this summer*:

> Hill recalled an argument she had **this summer** with Gordon Sondland,
>   Trump’s ambassador to the European Union, who was by then deeply
>   involved in a secretive effort to get Ukraine to launch
>   investigations.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this page because of this: Today is November 3, 2021. On PBS NewsHour a reporter said, "the murder of George Floyd sparked wide protests last summer." That struck me as questionable wording, ergo, my google search that brought me here. Because of the reaction I had, it is clear to me that I normally consider that statement to be referring to the summer that has most recently passed, namely, summer 2021, with the possible exception of during a short time period after summer 2021 when it may still seem like summer. But the George Floyd protests were in summer 2020. Here in November 2021 I would call that "the summer of last year" but not "last summer."